# how to copy selected file without moving it to another directory in python

Tags: python

i am trying to copy the selected images to another directory. I have tried **shutil.move()** and **shutil.copy** and **shutil.copy2**. these move the selected file. but i want to just make copy that and move that copy to required dir.

**code**

```
cwd = os.getcwd()
filepath = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(filepath))
shutil.move('{0}/{1}'.format(filepath, filename), '{0}/modeldata/temp/{1}'.format(cwd, filename))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `shutil.copyfile(src, dst)`

```
import os
import shutil

cwd = os.getcwd()
filepath = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(filepath))
shutil.copyfile(os.path.join(filepath, filename), os.path.join(cwd, 'modeldata/temp/' filename))
```

Read more here:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html

Comment: it is shutil.shutil.copyfile()  or shutil.copyfile()

Comment: Also nice: using pathlib. `shutil.copyfile(Path(filepath).parent / filename, Path.cwd() / 'modeldata' / 'temp' / filename)`

Comment: @Masklinn, `Path(filepath).with_name(filename)`

Comment: @OlvinRoght `parent` is the "official" replacement for dirname, I'm not entirely sure `with_name` matches those semantics 100% so I wasn't quite comfortable with using that (though in this case it probably doesn't matter).

Comment: @Frank, `pathlib` is replacement for `os.path` functions, so mixing this two approaches is weird. [Here](https://tio.run/##TU1LDgIhDN1ziu4GEuLGtYfBgREMUAI1Zk6PdBR109f3yys7eczn3reKCZp/UIgQUsFKsGLZtxCdODxsUy@GvIabo/VphRgHLh8mleACB4bGcLKhZpOcPIi5NkY5Q0qJOfIO3DHkr6uBP24rDT977GhYEloXrSGzDEIuleUvrnp/AQ) is how it should work with `os.path`, and [here](https://tio.run/##PYtBCsMwDATvfoXIyYaSHvqR/CC4sYMFViRSlZDXO5Uhvc1oR3Jq4e3V2rozwad8FSsgCe8KC8u5Ys2ubxK1VHzf4/RT5@7Em3ojy8J4oJZ5i5T7zSA8@su4HMkHeMJAnHJNUeNgppnE4J@3dgE) is how it should work with `pathlib`.

Comment: @Masklinn, yes, in case if `filename` contains not just name of file but relative path, `.with_name()` won't work, you're right.

Comment: how get file name, i need help

Comment: @HabibUrRehman A naive way to do so: `filename = filepath.split("/")[-1]`

Comment: @Frank, correct ways to do this [`os.path.basename(filepath)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.basename) or [`Path(filepath).name`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.name)